# Extracting code from lk.bin (little kernel binary file) & preloader.bin - MTK6572, mediatek

Tags: bootloader, kernel, partitions

This is a changed question from the original, since nobody seemed to have answered, found most of the answer on my own.  As stated before, wanted to fix my userdata and fat area blocks after hacking my EBR1 on a MTK6572, as posted on my blog, how to:

http://elizabethswikis.blogspot.com/2014/10/update-tutoial-re-partition-mtk6572.html

Found the information using IDA Pro dissembler in the preloader.bin, here is how the code looks in IDA PRO:

```
ROM:00017520                 DCD 0x600000, 0, 0, 0 **< preloader**
ROM:00017530                 DCD 0x201A630, 0
ROM:00017538                 DCD 0x80000, 0, 0, 0  **< MBR**
ROM:00017548                 DCD 0x201A634, 0
ROM:00017550                 DCD 0x80000, 0, 0, 0  **< EBR1**
ROM:00017560                 DCD 0x201A639, 0
ROM:00017568                 DCD 0x300000, 0, 0, 0 **< pro_info**
ROM:00017578                 DCD 0x201A642, 0
ROM:00017580                 DCD 0x500000, 0, 0, 0 **< NVRAM**
ROM:00017590                 DCD 0x201A648, 0
ROM:00017598                 DCD 0xA00000, 0, 0, 0 **< Protect_F**
ROM:000175A8                 DCD 0x201A652, 0
ROM:000175B0                 DCD 0xA00000, 0, 0, 0 **< Protect_S**
ROM:000175C0                 DCD 0x201A65C, 0
ROM:000175C8                 DCD 0x20000, 0, 0, 0 **< SYS5**
ROM:000175D8                 DCD 0x201A663, 0
ROM:000175E0                 DCD 0x60000, 0, 0, 0 **< UBOOT**
ROM:000175F0                 DCD 0x201A669, 0
ROM:000175F8                 DCD 0x600000, 0, 0, 0 **< BOOTIMG**
ROM:00017608                 DCD 0x201A671, 0
ROM:00017610                 DCD 0x600000, 0, 0, 0 **< Recovery**
ROM:00017620                 DCD 0x201A67A, 0
ROM:00017628                 DCD 0x40000, 0, 0, 0 **< Secro_RO**
ROM:00017638                 DCD 0x201A684, 0
ROM:00017640                 DCD 0x80000, 0, 0, 0 **< MISC**
ROM:00017650                 DCD 0x201A689, 0
ROM:00017658                 DCD 0x300000, 0, 0, 0 **< LOGO**
ROM:00017668                 DCD 0x201A68E, 0
ROM:00017670                 DCD 0xA00000, 0, 0, 0 **< EXPDB**
ROM:00017680                 DCD 0x201A694, 0
ROM:00017688                 DCD 0x28A00000, 0, 0, 0 **< ANDROID**
ROM:00017698                 DCD 0x201A69E, 0
ROM:000176A0                 DCD 0x17800000, 0, 0, 0 **< CACHE**
ROM:000176B0                 DCD 0x201A6A4, 0
ROM:000176B8                 DCD 0x20000000, 0, 0, 0 **< USERDATA**
ROM:000176C8                 DCD 0x201A6A9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

This actually throws me because the first time I successfully dissembled it, could have sworn that the fat was there, can't remember what I did or if it was the case, maybe I imagined it...  The disassembly isn't really correct, still working on it.  Two theory is, it did not do it correctly, need to find the correct size, or, if I were to change the userdata would that relocate the fat and bmtpool, which also isn't decoding BTW.